# No VMKernel Dump File on PSOD for ESXi 4

Tags: vmware-esxi

On PSOD no VMKernel Dump File is written to disk and no message is written to screen (the screen is either blank or full of dashes). I need this data to understand why the system crashes; any help as to how to fix this to write a dump file would be appreciated. Thanks.

Notes:

1. VMKCore partition exists, is active, and is configured (esxcfg-dumppart -l).
2. esxcfg-advcfg -g /Misc/PsodOnCosPanic = 1.
3. esxcfg-advcfg -g /Misc/CosCoreFile = /var/core.
4. esxcfg-dumppart -C -D /vmfs/devices/disks/ = "Error running command. Unable to copy the dump partition: Couldn't find a valid VMKernel dump file. Dump partition might be uninitialized."
5. Hardware diagnostics (Dell) checks okay.

Hardware:

VMWare ESXi 4.1.0 (VMKernel Release Build 320137)

Dell Inc. Optiplex 960 (2 Drives)

Intel Core 2 Quad CPU Q9400 2.66GHz

Configuration:

2 Virtual Machines: Windows Server 2003 R2 Enterprise Edition SP2 (1 on each drive)

VM 1: Executes Batch Jobs (Has Internet Information Services 6)

VM 2: Database Server (Has SQL Server 2000)

Comment: Do you have 10 Gig NICs on the machine?  I know that there was a bug in 4.1 that would cause PSoD if you had specific 10 Gig NIC drivers installed.  It is documented in the VMKB.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have an Intel 825xx 10/100/1000. If you are referring to http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1029368 as the bug I have already installed the patch (http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1029398) but it did not fix the problem.